# How to reduce yellow component in image?

Tags: opencv

I was trying to implement tone mapping in OpenCV by using logarithmic mapping, but the result I got was a yellowish image. So I want to reduce yellow component in image and increase other colors. Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated. Thank you.
The tone mapped image: [image: Its pink color image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to convert the image to HSV colorspace and offset colors (just shift Hue component).

Or reduce R and B components by the same ratio relative to G.

Here it my implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cv::namedWindow("result");
    Mat img=imread("yellowish.jpg");
    img.convertTo(img,CV_32FC3,1.0/255.0);

    Scalar m;
    m=cv::mean(img);
    img-=m;
    img+=Scalar(0.3,0.31,0.3); // Changing this you can adjust color balance.

    normalize(img,img,0,1,cv::NORM_MINMAX);
    imshow("result",img);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
}
```

The result shown below:
[image]

Comment: Can u elaborate on second method u mentioned?

Comment: To my question I have added the image.Please forgive me, I have uploaded pinkish image since I modified my program a bit. Hope u can suggest techniques to reduce the pink component in image. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

convert your image to HSV as following:

```
cvtColor(image, hsv_image, CV_RGB2HSV);
```

then split your "hsv_image" into its individual channels:

```
Mat channel[3];
split( hsv_image, channel );
```

so, now your `channel[0]` is an image based upon Hue-component. Usually the value of "Yellow" color have a hue range 22-38. So, now access each pixel of your hue-image (i.e. `channel[0]`) and make some `if()` condition as per your requirement.

Comment: To which hue value I should translate so that I get back original image?